# Is there a way to properly format a large numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a large 200x100 2d tuple (tuple of tuples) of floats that I'm trying to convert into a numpy array.

I do the conventional code:

```
arr = np.array(2d_tuple_of_floats)
```

But when I do that instead of converting into a 2d array, it converts into a 1d array of tuples (arr.shape = (200,)). So then I specify:

```
arr = np.array(2d_tuple_of_floats, ndmin=2)
```

And instead of changing to shape (200,100) it changes to the shape (1,200), implying that I simply have an array of 1 tuple of 200 tuples.
So then I try

```
arr = np.array(2d_tuple_of_floats, dtype=np.float, ndmin=2)
```

And it still remains as shape (1,200); I also tried making it as a matrix and converting the matrix to an array, but that did not work either.
How can I get it to the proper shape of (200,100)?

Edit:
For reference the tuple is formatted as:
((0,1/6.0,...),(0.0,1/9.0,...),...,(100/3.0+101/3.0,...))

Comment: That sounds like your inner tuples aren't actually all the same length. Figure out why and fix it.

Comment: `arr = np.array(2d_tuple_of_floats, ndmin=2)` should work, if not, tuples are probably not of the same lengths.

Comment: What is `arr.dtype`?   Did you look at `arr`, even just one part, `arr[0]`?  Most likely the tuples vary in length.

Comment: `np.stack(arr)` behaves like `np.array`, except it throws an error if the subarray shapes don't match.